# Basic Implementation of Equals in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have something like

```
data Example =
    Ex Integer
```

How would I go about implementing equals for this?

Furthest I have gotten is

```
instance Eq Example where 
    (Ex _) == (Ex _) = True
```

But that is wrong because that always evaluates to true. I could put concrete instances of an integer instead of the '_' character, but then I would have to do that for every integer.

Thanks for your time everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but then I would have to do that for every integer.

**No**, since `Integer` is a member of the `Eq` typeclass. We can thus make use of `(==)` implemented for `Integer`, and thus "unpack" the `Ex` data constructor, and check the equality of the parameters:

```
instance Eq Example where 
    Ex x == Ex y = x == y
```

That being said, you can let Haskell implement the `Eq` instance itself with:

```
data Example = Ex Integer deriving Eq
```

The automatic implementation of `Eq` specifies that two items are the same if they have the same *data constructor*, and the parameters are equal (with the `(==)` function).